# Making my switch statement work and print to console

Tags: java

Please note I am a beginner. Thanks for any help in advance. I want the value of type or whatPizza to print to the console via my switch statement depending on the String value or what the case value is within the switch statement. I currently am getting error and the program won't run. I know I might be missing some steps or my code isn't perfect or could be better in terms of other steps. If you could just help with the issue at hand, that'd be great!

```
class Main {

String type;
double price;
boolean order;

public Main(String whatPizza, double costOfPizza, boolean yourOrder){

  type = whatPizza;
  price = costOfPizza;
  order = yourOrder;

  if (price > 10.00){
    System.out.println("Thank you for spending over 10 pounds with us!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Thank you for buying with us!");
  }
  whatPizza = pizzaType();
}

  public String pizzaType(){
    switch(type){
      case "Pepperoni":
      System.out.println("You have picked a pepperoni pizza.");
      break;
      case "Cheese":
      System.out.println("You have picked a cheese pizza.");
      break;
      case "Ham":
      System.out.println("You have picked a ham pizza.");
      break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Please choose a type of pizza from menu");
    }
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //empty for now
  Main personA = new Main("Pepperoni", 11.00, true);
  Main personB = new Main("Cheese", 9.00, true);
  Main personC = new Main ("Ham", 10.00, false);

    }
  }
```

Comment: You do not return any String from `pizzaType` method.  You need either to return some stub string `return type;` or make this method `void` and fix its invocation in the constructor `pizzaType()`.  Or you should return the values from `switch` statement and use single print statement in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method pizzaType() is missing a return statement:

```
public String pizzaType(){
    switch(type){
        case "Pepperoni":
            System.out.println("You have picked a pepperoni pizza.");
            break;
        case "Cheese":
            System.out.println("You have picked a cheese pizza.");
            break;
        case "Ham":
            System.out.println("You have picked a ham pizza.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please choose a type of pizza from menu");
    }

    return type;
}
```

Alternatively, make the method signature return void:

```
public void pizzaType() {
```

There's no good reason to assign a value to `whatPizza` in the constructor.

Comment: Hi. All it needed was a return type; where you said. Without that and me removing whatPizza = pizzaType() from the constructor didn't work. Thanks for your help in fixing this :-)

Comment: In the constructor, just called pizzaType() without the assignment will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Method String pizzaType, you should return String. If you want to read about return.
I recommend this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-keyword-java/.

All you need to fix your problem, just to edit your method to :

```
   public String pizzaType(){
    String output="";
        switch(type){
          case "Pepperoni":
         output= "You have picked a pepperoni pizza";
          break;
          case "Cheese":
          output ="You have picked a cheese pizza.";
          break;
          case "Ham":
          output ="You have picked a ham pizza.";
          break;
          default:
            output ="Please choose a type of pizza from menu";
            }
return output;
}
```

And you should call method pizza type in main, or where o you want.
If you want just to print in main :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //empty for now
  Main personA = new Main("Pepperoni", 11.00, true);
  Main personB = new Main("Cheese", 9.00, true);
  Main personC = new Main ("Ham", 10.00, false);
// Example
String result =personA.pizzaType();
System.out.print(result);
    }
```